# Per-user permissions for Drupal file upload

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I have a Drupal 6 site where I want to share files with clients. I've set up an account on the site for each client. Now I want to upload files so that the clients can download them.

The thing is, I want to set the site permissions so that only the client can download their files. Clients should not be able to download files that are intended for other clients.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read about these modules:

- [User Files](http://drupal.org/project/user_files)
- [filedepot](http://drupal.org/project/filedepot)
- [Asset](http://drupal.org/project/asset)

The first seems to suit best. YMMV

Comment: Thanks! Wound up going with filedepot.